# HealthKit HKSampleQuery Heart rate readings

Tags: ios8, healthkit, hksamplequery

I'm trying to get heart rate readings through the healthkit store using HKSampleQuery, but I keep getting count/s. Is there anyway I can get it by count/minute?

Comment: is it `count/sec`? How about a divide by 60?

Answer (score 2):

Try using something like the following in the completion handler of a `HKSampleQuery`

```
let result = results?.last as HKQuantitySample
let quantity = result.quantity
let count = quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit(fromString: "count/min"))
```